# Paypal API update order shipping company, order status and tracking number

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have searched the PayPal API docs and google but I cannot find a sample for me to be able to achieve this:

Once I have received a "VERIFIED" payment from the PayPal API and done the necessary checks to prevent fraud etc, is there an available PayPal API call I can make to send back to PayPal the following details:

1. Order Status: "Service Rendered"
2. Tracking No: Unique identifier from my system
3. Shipping Company: My Company name

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, no, there is no API to push shipping/tracking details to a PayPal transaction.  I've been begging for it for years.

Comment: PayPal know better what you need stupid customers. Obvious feature that can't be added for many years